# Gradle build failing with "Could not resolve ...${javassist.version}... Illegal character in path

Tags: maven, gradle

In my Gradle dependencies file I am depending on:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'net.johnluetke.WeatherAPI:WeatherAPI:0.9.4'
```

WeatherAPI in turn depends on org.reflections, which has a Maven profile-based dependency on javassist.

The error I get when trying to build my (Java 8) app is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.javassist:javassist:${javassist.version}.
Required by:
  :weatherenrich:0.1.0 > net.johnluetke.WeatherAPI:WeatherAPI:0.9.4 > org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9-RC2
 > Illegal character in path at index 55: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist /${javassist.version}/javassist-${javassist.version}.pom
```

How do I get my app building?

Answer (score 3):

Gradle does not support resolving placeholders in published POMs - for more information on this see [this support thread](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/handling_properties_in_maven_pom).

Fortunately, Gradle can resolve a system property with the same name.

If we go into the pom.xml for `org.reflections:reflections` we can see the profiles setup for javassist:

https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/pom.xml#L129

Because the app is Java 8, we want the profile for any JRE except version 5, so we want:

```
<javassist.version>3.18.2-GA</javassist.version>
```

Therefore, in the root of the Java app, add a file `gradle.properties`, and add this entry:

```
systemProp.javassist.version=3.18.2-GA
```

The app should then build.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser, I figured it from your answers in that thread!

Comment: Gradle does support replacing placeholders in published POMs when parsing them. The problem you are seeing here is related to parsing POM profiles. There are only specific profile activation criteria Gradle takes into account: active by default, activation on absence of system property. That's not the case for this POM.